# why is my web3 import not working properly?

Tags: mocha.js, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle

I am using truffle with mocha to test my smart contract. I have required web3 like so
`const web3 = require('web3')`

the import seems only to work partially.
for example, this statement works just fine

`const amount = web3.utils.toWei('0.23')`

however this statement

`const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(myContract.address)`

causes the following error message:

TypeError Cannot read property 'getBalance' of undefined.

Moreover, Visual Studio Code gives me the following error message if I hover of the word eth in this following code:

`web.eth.getBalance(myContract.address)`

Property 'eth' does not exist on typeof import (/Users/eitanbronschtein/Desktop/fundraiser/node_modules/web3/types/index)

I am using javascript and not typescript.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

web3 does not work without provider. install [ganach-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ganache-cli)

```js
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");

// this is in local ganache network gasLimit has to be set to 10million and and factory gas must be 10million
// if u get error about gasLimit, this keep changing. look for docs
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider({ gasLimit: 10000000 }));
```

If you set truffle suit, you should have "test" directory in your project and `web3` would be already set and available globally

Answer (score 1):

From https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.5/web3.html:

> The Web3 class is an umbrella package to house all Ethereum related modules.

```js
var Web3 = require('web3');

// "Web3.providers.givenProvider" will be set if in an Ethereum supported browser.
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://some.local-or-remote.node:8546');

//now you can do web3.eth
```